# How to change location of ~/.vim

Tags: vimrc, linux, environment-variables

I have Vim 7 installed from my distro's package manager, and I compiled Vim 8 from source. Vim 8 is all in /usr/local. Then I created a new directory in $HOME called ".vim8". I have all my Vim 7 stuff in $HOME/.vim/, and I want a clean directory for Vim 8 in $HOME/.vim8/.

For Vim 8, I'm calling it like this: `/usr/local/bin/vim8 -u "${HOME}/.vim8/vimrc"`.

That sets the vimrc to the right file. But it still doesn't load other things in `${HOME}/.vim8/`. For example, I have the NERDTree plugin installed in pack:

```
$ tree -L 5 $HOME/.vim8/
/home/todd/.vim8/
├── pack
│   └── vendor
│       └── start
│           └── nerdtree
│               ├── autoload
│               ├── CHANGELOG.md
│               ├── doc
│               ├── lib
│               ├── LICENCE
│               ├── nerdtree_plugin
│               ├── plugin
│               ├── README.markdown
│               ├── screenshot.png
│               └── syntax
└── vimrc
```

Yet the plugin doesn't load. When I open vim8 I can't use NERDTree. It says it's not an editor command. Thinking about why this would be happening, I came up with a possibility: maybe it's using `$HOME/.vim8/vimrc` as the rc file, but it's *not* using `$HOME/.vim8` for everything else. So I did this:

```
$ vim8 -u "${HOME}/.vim8/vimrc" -T dumb -c ':scriptnames|:q'

  1: ~/.vim8/vimrc
  2: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: ~/.vim/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
     [ ...and a bunch of other files from local... ]
```

Aha! It appears I'm right. Vim is still looking in the .vim/ directory. So then I try setting runtimepath:

```
$ vim8 -u "${HOME}/.vim8/vimrc" --cmd ':set runtimepath=~/.vim8/,$VIMRUNTIME' -T dumb -c ':scriptnames|:q'

  1: ~/.vim8/vimrc
  2: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/local/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
     [ ...and a bunch of other files from local... ]
```

And now it's not loading anything from .vim/. That's good. But also still not loading anything from .vim8/. NERDTree is still not available.

How do I tell Vim to use an alternate user directory for runtime files? I want to keep the 7 and 8 configuration separate and side-by-side. Is there anything I can do make Vim 8 use `$HOME/.vim8/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specific path you're using (`pack/vendor/start/nerdtree`) is using the ["packages" feature](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages), which is a new Vim 8 feature that automates manipulation of `'runtimepath'` in a way similar to how plug-in managers have been implemented.

That's why your attempt setting `'runtimepath'` from `--cmd` doesn't work, since packages actually use a separate `'packpath'` setting.

The location of `~/.vim` is only set in Vim as part of those two options: [`'runtimepath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) and [`'packpath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27packpath%27).

So you can override that to `~/.vim8` by simply resetting these two options in the `.vimrc` you use with Vim 8:

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim8,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,~/.vim8/after
set packpath=~/.vim8,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,~/.vim8/after
```

This should be enough to have Vim read files from the separate directory.

---

If you're building Vim 8 from sources, you might also want to consider patching it so it defaults to looking at `~/.vim8` rather than `~/.vim`.

You can change those default paths [in `src/os_unix.h`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/os_unix.h#L371-L382).

While at it, you might want to consider changing the [location of the vimrc file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/os_unix.h#L263) and also the [second vimrc file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/os_unix.h#L272) which is typically under `~/.vim`, so you might want to update that one.

---

Please note that some plug-ins (in particular, plug-in managers) might use `~/.vim` as their default as well (or even hardcode that path), so you might need to deal with those separately.

For example, Vundle [defaults to using `~/.vim/bundle`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/v0.10.2/autoload/vundle.vim#L63), but you can easily override that in the `vundle#begin()` call by passing a directory as an argument. (vim-plug, a more modern plug-in manager and in a way successor to Vundle, doesn't have this problem and will use the first path in `'runtimepath'` instead as its default.)

---

Also consider whether you *really* want and need to keep separate `~/.vim` directories for Vim 7 and Vim 8. Vim has enough features that should make it possible/easy to keep a single config that works in multiple versions.

For example, with Vim 8 packages, you can use a check such as `if has('packages')` to check whether the feature is enabled or not. If support for packages is not available, you can use [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to load the plug-ins from the package directories, so you can have selective backwards compatibility for those too.

Comment: This is a very complete answer -- especially for pointing out where in the source the vimrc default is set! -- and very well written. Thank you. I do want to keep separate .vim directories because I want to test out Vim 8 with a clean config. I really like @Matt 's suggestion (in another answer) of putting that switch in the main/usual vimrc.

Comment: What Is vim-pathogen the difference between `vim-pathogen` and `vim-plug`? I should use the latter one? I'm new to Vim.

Comment: @Niing Yes, use vim-plug, it makes it very easy to manage plug-ins and it's pretty friendly to beginners. Pathogen is very similar to what Vim packages in Vim 8 do, and that depends on you fetching and updating the plug-ins yourself. vim-plug makes that easier, since it will install and update them for you.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from [Patch 7.4.1384](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.1384) Vim has [`'packpath'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27packpath%27) option for searching plugins. By default `'packpath'` is equal to `'runtimepath'` (until `'runtimepath'` finally gets inflated by the plugins loaded), so you must keep them sync in your vimrc.

> For Vim 8, I'm calling it like this: /usr/local/bin/vim8 -u "${HOME}/.vim8/vimrc".

You can add the following lines on top of your "main" vimrc instead:

```
" check if we have version-specific config
let s:dotvim = '~/.vim' . (v:version / 100)
if isdirectory(expand(s:dotvim))
    " setup runtimepath and packpath
    set runtimepath=$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after
    execute 'set runtimepath^=' . s:dotvim
    execute 'set runtimepath+=' . s:dotvim . '/after'
    if exists('&packpath')
        let &packpath = &runtimepath
    endif
    " proceed with special config
    execute 'source' s:dotvim . '/vimrc'
    finish
endif
" default stuff (if any) follows...
```

Now an appropriate configuration will be chosen automatically.